# Why is load time for images so slow and variable?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

[image]My website loads most elements within 1-2 secs.

However, some of the images will take 6 seconds (or even up to 20 secs) to load. There seems to be no pattern to which images will take a long time to load. Most will load in under 1 sec but 2 or 3 will "wait" for 6 secs plus. This is obviously reducing the page load time.

I have served the images from a CDN (I know they dont show that here) but that still makes no difference and sometimes the images that take the longest to load are <1kb in size.

The website is hosted on an AWS EC2 t2.micro instance. I am using W3TC and Cloudfront CDN. The images have been optimised.

I have included my CPU Credit Balance. This is also low. Might this be a problem?

Any ideas as to why random images will take a long time to be served?

[image]

Comment: You appear to be using CloudFront for the js but not thr images.  Have you verified that the CPU credit balance on the instance is not depleted?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot For some reason I cant get cloudfront to upload the images. Everything else is served by CloudFront but it wont load the images. I have attached my CPU Credit balance. I'm not sure what I'm looking for or how to fix it?